# Reuse instances of case classes

Tags: scala, memory-management, case-class

Suppose my application uses a lot of `Move` objects over and over durring a long period of time, where `Move` is defined as follows:

```
sealed trait Player
case object P1 extends Player
case object P2 extends Player
case object P3 extends Player
case object P4 extends Player

sealed trait Key
case object Up extends Key
case object Down extends Key
case object Right extends Key
case object Left extends Key
case object Space extends Key

sealed trait Action
case object Press extends Action
case object Release extends Action

case class Input(key: Key, action: Action)
case class Move(input: Input, player: Player)
```

That's 10 different possible `Input`s, and 40 different `Move`s. Is there a way to ask the compiler to optimise these types by creating all the possible `Move`s once and reusing the instances over time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a scalaz `Memo`:

```
val moveCache = Memo.mutableHashMapMemo{ip: (Input, Player) => Move(ip._1, ip._2)}
....
val myMove = moveCache((myInput, myPlayer))
```

Honestly I very much doubt this would have a significant effect on performance. Before making your code less readable, make sure you have clear profiling results that show that it actually makes the difference you think.

Comment: Object allocation on a modern generational GC is *extremely* fast. Faster than `malloc`, equally fast as stack allocation. Garbage collection of short-lived small immutable objects is also extremely fast. With object pooling or caching, you basically break the assumptions that make GC fast in the first place: you artificially prolong their lifetime (making them no longer short-lived), you introduce an even longer lived giant object (the cache or pool itself), and depending on your use case, you also make objects mutable that wouldn't otherwise need to be to reuse them in a different state.

Comment: Or, to put it short: +1, measure first, cut later!